# Getting available methods/properties for various types in javascript

Tags: javascript

To see the methods available to an object I am able to do:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object));
```

But then why doesn't it give the properties when I pass it an instance of a particular object type (I hope that is the correct terminology?). For example, in the following `n` has one method called `toFixed` but it doesn't show up when trying to get the property names.

```js
let n = 1234.567;
console.log(n.toFixed(1));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(n));
```

Comment: Read that function name carefully, and slow down when you get to the part where it says _Own_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getOwnPropertyNames`, as it sounds, gets only the *own properties* of the object.

But numbers are primitives, not objects - and `toFixed` is on `Number.prototype`, not on Number instances. The number has no own properties.

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Number.prototype));
```

For another example, with a proper object:

```js
class X {
  protoMethod(){}
}
const x = new X();

// Empty:
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x));
// The prototype has the own-property of the method:
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(X.prototype));
```

Comment: Instead of writing `Number.prototype` is there a way to introspect it, so it's something like `(typeof n).prototype` ?

Comment: Yes, `Object.getPrototypeOf(n)` to get the internal prototype of the passed expression

Comment: hmm, I get `{}` for doing `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(n));` but I get the methods when doing `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Number.prototype));`

Comment: `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(5));` works fine for me

Comment: k I'll post another question for it. I tried it in the Stackoverflow interpreter and it just gave me `{}` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf). All the methods are defined in the prototype of the object.

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(n));
```